# Why are my tag statistics different on mobile vs desktop?

Tags: discussion, bug, tags, statistics

I have different scores next to my tags depending on whether I'm looking in my desktop web browser or mobile app. What is the explanation?

[image: Desktop version]

[image: Mobile version]

Comment: The title of the tag has the explanation: *Asked 25 non-wiki questions with a total score of 185. Gave 34 non-wiki answers with a total score of 114.* 185+114 = 299. Looks like on the desktop version only answers are considered to be important????

Comment: @rene Haha, is it the first time you see that "on the desktop version only answers are considered to be important"? But you know why has it been done this way?

Comment: @nicael I answered the dupe: balpha explained here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212315/158100

Comment: @rene clarified my comment :) The tag scores are intentionally counting only the answer score, this is inline with the answer tag badges. The logical question would be, why isn't it done this way in the app.

Comment: @nicael stop trolling me ;)